# Анимация перемещения метки на карте Яндекс

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yandex-maps-api

Я создаю виджет для отслеживания местоположения курьера. Передвижение курьера должно отображаться на карте в реальном времени. Имеется ли в api яндекс карт возможность перемещать метки программно из точки A в точку B? И если нет, то как это можно реализовать на яндекс картах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Зачем вам перемещать курьера? Его метку достаточно просто наложить поверх карты в центре, а перемещать саму карту через [setCenter](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/archive/doc/jsapi/1.x/ref/reference/map.html#method_detail__setCenter).
2. Отслеживание курьера или любых других объектов в реальном времени - [коммерческий кейс](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/). Имейте это в виду при разработке и дальнейшем использовании.

Comment: Спасибо за вариант решения. Также смог реализовать через setCoordinates для геообъекта.